# Multi maven spring config

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, ear

I am trying to deploy to server one ear which contains:
ServiceA war
ServiceB war
springconfig war
I tried my config with single maven module and it worked but now it does not work with ear and multiple modules.
My Config:

DispatcherConfig

```
public class DispatcherConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
}
```

RootConfig

```
 @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.controllers"},
            excludeFilters = {
                    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)
            })
    public class RootConfig {
    }
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.controllers")
public class WebConfig
        extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Ear pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>earmodule</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceB</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>springconfig</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <!-- configuring the ear plugin -->
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>test</groupId>
                            <artifactId>serviceA</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>test</groupId>
                            <artifactId>serviceB</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>test</groupId>
                            <artifactId>springconfig</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

ServiceA pom(service 2 pom is similar like this one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>serviceA</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class ControllerA {

    @RequestMapping(value = "aservice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Neki log da smo usli u kontroler");
        return "aservice";
    }
}
```

When I try to access controller I got message:

```
JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
```

Log during deployment:

```
15:12:46,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "earmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" (runtime-name: "earmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")
15:12:46,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-30) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "serviceB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
15:12:46,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-48) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "springconfig-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
15:12:46,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "serviceA-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
15:12:47,517 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-23) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:12:47,518 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-23) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
15:12:47,562 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) JBAS018210: Register web context: /serviceB
15:12:47,562 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) JBAS018210: Register web context: /serviceA
15:12:47,585 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) JBAS018210: Register web context: /springconfig
15:12:47,596 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/springconfig]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
15:12:47,638 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/springconfig]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
15:12:47,638 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
15:12:47,649 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri May 19 15:12:47 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
15:12:47,710 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Registering annotated classes: [class config.RootConfig]
15:12:47,869 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15:12:47,929 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 290 ms
15:12:47,930 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/springconfig]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
15:12:47,930 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
15:12:47,933 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri May 19 15:12:47 CEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
15:12:47,933 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Registering annotated classes: [class config.WebConfig]
15:12:48,024 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15:12:48,189 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
15:12:48,293 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final-redhat-1
15:12:48,342 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri May 19 15:12:47 CEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
15:12:48,472 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 542 ms
```

Comment: Are you trying to share classes and or jars between web modules? That won't work because web modules are not permitted to see each other's classes

Comment: @SteveC Thank you for answer. I am not sure that I understood you. I am trying to share config(in my case is spring config) over more than one web module. I tried with spring config being jar but that didnt worked too.